# What am I doing wrong? Trying to use context-param in web.xml with ServletContextListener

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I am trying to use init-param in my web-app, and use it together with ServletContextListener. This should later be picked up my the servlet and displayed to the user. I have done everything I can, but I am getting an error. Something is wrong and I can't see it.

My web.xml

```
<web-app>
<context-param>
<param-name>name</param-name>
<param-value>Abdi</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

My class:

```
@WebListener
 public class Developer implements ServletContextListener{


@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {


    System.out.println("Destroyed!");



}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
    ServletContext cntxt = e.getServletContext();

    String name = e.getServletContext().getInitParameter(name); 

    DevInfo student = new DevInfo(name);

    cntxt.setAttribute("student", student); 

}



  }
```

Other class:

```
public class DevInfo {

private String name;


public DevInfo (String name) {
    this.name = name;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

}
```

Servlet:

```
   DevInfo stu = (DevInfo)getServletContext().getAttribute("student");

    System.out.println("Developers name is: " + stu.getName());
```

My error is in the contextInitialized method. "The local variable name may not have been initialized" at e.getServletContext().getInitParameter(name);

Answer (score 2):

The actual way to get the `context-param`'s `param-value` is to pass the `param-name` on the [`getInitParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter(java.lang.String)) method:

```
String name = e.getServletContext().getInitParameter("name");
```

You forgot to put `name` in quotes.

Comment: Yes, I fixed that, thank you. Problem gone. Now I have a new problem. "Developers name is: null"

Comment: What is the value returned by `e.getServletContext().getInitParameter("name")`?

Comment: The value of name is in my web.xml. I specified that in my question.

Comment: You don't understand. If you debug the application, what's the result (return value) from that line of code?

Comment: No, I don't understand. I get null.

Comment: Then post your `web.xml` to see how you configured your context.

Comment: Updated the question with web-xml. Value is always null

Comment: Just a note: your `web-app` element in your `web.xml` is incomplete. Try adding the related XSD to the attribute (see example): `<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">`. Latest version XSD is `web-app_3_0.xsd`. I don't know if this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hatuti: *"Problem gone. Now I have a new problem."* Please don't chameleonize existing questions for an infinite array of new problems. Your initial question is answered and your initial problem is solved. If you have a new problem, just ask a new question. This is in no way related to the initial question/problem.